# Get serial port data to a text box (.net 3.5)

Tags: asp.net

I need to get serial port data to a textbox in the page, when I scan the barcode using a barcode scanner. 
Can anyone tell me how to do this in asp.net 3.5?
On data received in serial port, that data should appear in textbox.
I am new to .net.

thanks

Comment: Are you sure you mean ASP.net? And if so, is the serial port on the server or the client?

Comment: yes. serial port on the client. basically when the barcode scanner scans something I need to get the data from the port and get the corresponding records from the database and display everything in the boxes accordingly.

Comment: I worked on a similar project. Like Micheal Todd stated, i set the focus of the text box in which i wanted to display the data. To use the value i hooked up the TextChanged event of the text box.

Answer (score 0):

We have a system set up similarly here. We put the barcode reader into a mode whereby it outputs the characters that make up the barcode as if the user had typed them from the keyboard. So, to scan something and make it appear in a textbox, we would set Focus to the textbox, then scan the barcode and, voila, the text would appear.

That's just one way to do it. You could get a serial port reader "module" and incorporate it into your application, but I think this is much easier.

Comment: you are right. if I just want to display the barcode in a textbox I can do that. But this is different. I need to take the value,get the records from database for that value and input that as well. Again they can scan the different type of barcodes for eg, product id, product serail no in any order. If I can get the data from serial port I can manipulate it and display accordingly.

Comment: When we were looking into it, the various barcode readers had APIs available for them. I imagine that that would be a good place to start. It's possible that getting a serial port reader would be useful, but it's also very likely that the manufacturers obfuscate the information as much as possible so that you _have_ to use their stuff. I'd start with the barcode vendor and see if they have options.